# javascript setTimeout and issues with a bunch of circles

Tags: javascript

I have a small program that I am supposed to write that makes a bouncy ball in a canvas. I can get a wireframe of a ball bouncing, but can't seem to get the setTimeout to fire at all. I have read, read and read about the function, but can't figure this out (new).

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>basic Canvas</title>
      <style>
         #canvas1{
            border:1px solid #9C9898;
         }
         body{
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
        }
      </style>
      <script>
         function drawMe(){
            //Set x,y,radius
            var x = 60;
            var y = 60;
            var radius = 70;
            drawLoop(x,y,radius);
         }

         function drawLoop(x,y,radius){
            var canvas2=document.getElementById("canvas1");
            var ctx=canvas2.getContext("2d");
            for(i=1;i<100;i++){

                    if(y + radius >= canvas2.height){
                        d = 1;
                    }
                    if(y - radius <= 0){
                        d = 0;
                    }
                    if (d==0){
                        x = x + 10;
                        y = y + 10;
                    }
                    else if (d==1){
                        x = x + 10;
                        y = y - 10;
                    }
                    draw(x,y,radius);
                    window.setTimeout(function() {draw(x,y,radius)},3000);
                }
         }

         function draw(x,y,radius){
                    var canvas2=document.getElementById("canvas1");
                    var ctx=canvas2.getContext("2d");

                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(x,y,radius,0,2*Math.PI,false);
                    var gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(x, y, 1, x, y, radius);
                    gradient.addColorStop(0,"blue");
                    gradient.addColorStop(1,"white");
                    ctx.fillStyle=gradient;
                    ctx.lineWidth=1;
                    ctx.strokeStyle="blue";
                    ctx.fill();
                    ctx.stroke();
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body onload="drawMe()">
      <canvas id="canvas1" width=1000" height="400">

      </canvas>
   </body>
</html>
```

A little function called 'drawMe()' which sets x, y, and radius, then calls a little drawing loop that fires 100 times that draws the bouncy ball ('drawLoop'). at the bottom of the function drawLoop, I call draw, which actually drawls the circles. From what I've read, the line 'setTimeout(function(){draw(x,y,radius)};,3000); should call the draw function every three seconds. But it doesn't. What the heck am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setTimeouts are counted from the time they are created.  The loop runs almost instantly and creates the setTimeouts at almost the same time.  They are then all ran 3 seconds later.

One way to get around this is in the solution below.  This does not increment the loop until the current timeout has been completed.
http://jsfiddle.net/x8PWg/14/

This is only one of the many potential solutions to this.